# How to parse CDATA XML using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am working on a web service written in PHP. I want to display data using IEEE Explore API -- it's a REST API. It outputs XML, as below.

I want to parse this data using a `foreach` loop. I tried to retrieve the data. But the problem is that all tag values are inside the **`CDATA`** wrappers.

How can I solve this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <rank>1</rank>
    <title><![CDATA[Gait Rhythm Fluctuation Analysis for Neurodegenerative Diseases by Empirical Mode Decomposition]]></title>
    <authors><![CDATA[Peng Ren;  Shanjiang Tang;  Fang Fang;  Lizhu Luo;  Lei Xu;  Maria L. Bringas-Vega;  Dezhong Yao;  Keith M. Kendrick;  Pedro A. Valdes-Sosa]]></authors>
    <controlledterms>
        <term><![CDATA[diseases]]></term>
        <term><![CDATA[feature extraction]]></term>
        <term><![CDATA[gait analysis]]></term>
    </controlledterms>
    <pubtitle><![CDATA[IEEE Transactions on Biomedical Engineering]]></pubtitle>
    <punumber><![CDATA[10]]></punumber>
    <pubtype><![CDATA[Journals &amp; Magazines]]></pubtype>
    <publisher><![CDATA[IEEE]]></publisher>
    <abstract><![CDATA[Previous studies have indicated that gait rhythm of gait rhythms.]]></abstract>
    <issn><![CDATA[0018-9294]]></issn>
    <arnumber><![CDATA[7422732]]></arnumber>
    <doi><![CDATA[10.1109/TBME.2016.2536438]]></doi>
    <publicationId><![CDATA[7422732]]></publicationId>
    <partnum><![CDATA[7422732]]></partnum>
</document>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the code:

```
<?php
//require_once 'connection.php';
function xmlToArray($xml,$ns=null){
 $a = array();
 for($xml->rewind(); $xml->valid(); $xml->next()) {
  $key = $xml->key();
  if(!isset($a[$key])) { $a[$key] = array(); $i=0; }
  else $i = count($a[$key]);
  $simple = true;
  foreach($xml->current()->attributes() as $k=>$v) {
   $a[$key][$i][$k]=(string)$v;
   $simple = false;
  }
  if($ns) foreach($ns as $nid=>$name) {
   foreach($xml->current()->attributes($name) as $k=>$v) {
    $a[$key][$i][$nid.':'.$k]=(string)$v;
    $simple = false;
   }
  }
  if($xml->hasChildren()) {
   if($simple) $a[$key][$i] = xmlToArray($xml->current(), $ns);
   else $a[$key][$i]['content'] = xmlToArray($xml->current(), $ns);
  } else {
   if($simple) $a[$key][$i] = strval($xml->current());
   else $a[$key][$i]['content'] = strval($xml->current());
  }
  $i++;
 }
 return $a;
}

$xml = new SimpleXmlIterator('test.xml', null, true);
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
// echo '<pre>'; print_r($namespaces); die;
$arr = xmlToArray($xml,$namespaces);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr); die;
?>
```

I am able to get the value of the fields resides in CDATA. place your XML data in `test.xml` file.

Comment: you code is little complex to understand please simplify.

Answer (score -1):

I find another simple solutions for my problem when reading php.net documentation it gives solution. I simply pass my url like this `$xml = simplexml_load_file($mainurl, 'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);`. I get my complete data.